# Transferring a list to a class

Tags: c, struct

I have a list of checkpoints and then a run a function. I originally built this list in that function, but now I have to build it outside. The problem is that I cannot include `checkpoint.h` in the class that implements that function because `checkpoint.h` returns a structure of the type of that class. The initial list was declare in `class.c` globally. How can  I transfer the list created outside into class so I can use it?

So I have this header, `turing_machine.h`:

```
#ifndef __TURING_MACHINE__ 
#define __TURING_MACHINE__

#include "tape.h"
#include "alphabet.h"
#include "symbol_table.h"

...

#endif
```

and the `checkpoint.h` header defining the `checkpoint_list` class:

```
#ifndef __CHECKPOINT_H__
#define __CHECKPOINT_H__

#include "turing_machine.h"

...

#endif
```

So I want to send to a function from `turing_machine.h` a list of structures `checkpoint` but I can't modify anything because that's how the classes must stay.

I have also `turing_machine.c`:

```
#include "turing_machine.h"
#include "checkpoint.h"
#include "symbol_table.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

checkpoint_list *c;
```

So at the beginning I created in turing_machine that list, `c`, but now I must create it outside and I have to initialize that list `c` but I don't know how. I hope this is more clear.

I used the term class wrong; I have just `.c` and `.h` files.

Comment: This makes no sense currently.  What do you mean when you say "checkpoint.h returns a structure"?  You should post some representative code, rather than trying to describe your code.

Comment: Also, you should accept some of the answers to your previous questions if they adequately answered your questions.

Comment: Implementing classes in C has always been so hard... luckily there is a new thing out there called C++... have you try it? Looks promising!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading between the lines, somewhat, I think your trouble is that you have 'mutually referencing' structures.

The way to work around this is with an incomplete type definition:

```
typedef struct checkpoint_list checkpoint_list;
```

You can then use that inside `turing_machine.h`:

```
#ifndef TURING_MACHINE_H_INCLUDED
#define TURING_MACHINE_H_INCLUDED

#include "tape.h"
#include "alphabet.h"
#include "symbol_table.h"

typedef struct checkpoint_list checkpoint_list;

typedef struct turing_machine
{
    ...
} turing_machine;

extern checkpoint_list *tm_function(turing_machine *);
extern turing_machine  *tm_create(const char *); 

#endif
```

And, inside `checkpoint.h`, you can write:

```
#ifndef CHECKPOINT_H_INCLUDED
#define CHECKPOINT_H_INCLUDED

#include "turing_machine.h"

/* No typedef here in checkpoint.h */
struct checkpoint_list
{
    ...
};

extern checkpoint_list *cp_function(const char *);
extern turing_machine  *cp_machine(checkpoint_list *);

#endif
```

This technique is recognized and defined by the C standard (C90, let alone C99 or C11).

Note that I've also renamed the include guards; names that start with double underscore are reserved for 'the implementation' (meaning the C compiler and its libraries), and you should not invent and use such names in your own code.